# Data object defined in created function but NOT reactive?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a Vue instance where data property is initialised as an object:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    obj: { }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  created: function() {
    this.obj["obj2"] = {}
    this.obj["obj2"].count = 0
  },
  mounted: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      this.obj.obj2.count++
      console.log(this.obj.obj2.count)
    }.bind(this), 1000)
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ obj['obj2'].count }}
</div>
```

And then when the instance is created I add a property to the **obj**.

However, when I want to display the object's object property **count**, it shows 0 and is not reactive. If I defined the whole object in the data, it is reactive but I can't define the object in the data because its data depends on an external source - API, that's why it is filled with data in **created** function.

The only way how I managed to make it show the current count is by forcing updates on the view but I don't think it's the correct solution.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You might be doing the binding wrong, try
    `var self = this;
    setInterval(function() {
      self.obj.obj2.count++
      console.log(self.obj.obj2.count)
    }, 1000)`

Comment: @effy No, that's not the problem. It's something with how Vue binds the model to view and object initialization.

Comment: Have you tried returning a function from data, like so: `data: function(){return {obj: {}}}`.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @effy Yea, I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Vue can not track completely new properties on its reactive objects. (It's a limitation of JavaScript).

It's described in detail here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

The short version is: You have to do

```
created: function() {
  Vue.set(this.obj, 'obj2', {})
  Vue.set(this.obj.obj2, 'count', 0)
}
```

or

```
created: function() {
  Vue.set(this.obj, 'obj2', {
    count: 0
  })
}
```

Comment: God bless your kind soul! What an intriguing workaround.